# Get all folders google drive api on Android

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I use the new Google drive api and I can't get All folders from my google drive, I only get the folders that I create with the google drive api... 
Anybody know why happens this?

this is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            // Create the API client and bind it to an instance variable.
            // We use this instance as the callback for connection and connection
            // failures.
            // Since no account name is passed, the user is prompted to choose.
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
        // Connect the client. Once connected, the camera is launched.
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }


    /**
     * Handles resolution callbacks.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when activity gets invisible. Connection to Drive service needs to
     * be disconnected as soon as an activity is invisible.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    /**
     * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} is connected.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connected");

        rootFolder = Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mGoogleApiClient);

       rootFolder.listChildren(getGoogleApiClient()).setResultCallback(pruebaChildren);

    }


    ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult> pruebaChildren = new
            ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult metadataBufferResult) {
                    if (!metadataBufferResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        showMessage("Problem while retrieving files");
                        return;
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG,"got root folder");
                    MetadataBuffer buffer = metadataBufferResult.getMetadataBuffer();
                    Log.i(TAG,"Buffer count  " + buffer.getCount());
                    if(buffer.getCount() == 0){
                        createFolderApp();
                    }
                    else{
                        for(Metadata m : buffer){
                            Log.i(TAG,"Metadata name  " + m.getTitle() + "(" + (m.isFolder() ? "folder" : "file") + ")");
                            if (m.isFolder() && m.getTitle().equals(TAG)){
                                Log.i(TAG,"APP FOLDER FOUND");
                                Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(mGoogleApiClient, m.getDriveId())
                                        .listChildren(mGoogleApiClient)
                                        .setResultCallback(foreachAppAplication);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return;
                }
            };
```

And now I want see all folders in rootFolder Drive, I try the requestSync() but the result is same... I need help please!

And another question: How I can set the AppFolder? I only see getAppFolder but How I can set ??

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By design, [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro) supports only the FILE scope, i.e. it will find / list only folders / files created by the Android app.

There are 2 ways around it:

1. Use one of the *[intents](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos#intents)* of the GDAA, basically letting the user pick the file / folder. That way it will become available to your app.
2. Use a different API, the [REST](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk) Api, which supports the DRIVE scope, giving your app full set of files / folders.

In case you want to study how the two APIs behave, I've put two different demos on the Github (the [REST](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo) and the [GDAA](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo) CRUD demo wrappers).

The second part of your question does not have answer. You don't set the app folder, you can only get it's DriveFolder id. You use it to create / retrieve objects.

```
  DriveFolder appFldr = Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(mGooleApiClient);
  appFldr.createFile(...);
  appFldr.createFolder(...);
  appFldr.listChildren(...);
  appFldr.queryChildren(...);
```

... and don't forget to add the **SCOPE_APPFOLDER** scope

Good Luck

Comment: Hi, I'm prove by REST API but and now I can't set the credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName); ... I follow this example.
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/java

In debug I see that when I choose the new account, with this method not rewrite the credentials...

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/android#step_2_enable_the_api_name this example sorry

Comment: I don't know these quickstarts, take a look at the init() method [here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/spjanson/restdemo/REST.java)