# How to get list of all folders and files from google drive in android

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I have started developing a app in which i have to list of all folders and files from google drive.

I have go through all the documentation and below demo links as suggested in this stack overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760028/get-all-folders-google-drive-api-on-android),

https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos

And

https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo

I have make these both demo working properly. **But I am not able to list out all the folders and files of google drive.** Currently i can **only list out those files which are created by app only**. If there is any other folder created from web then it is not showing in the log or list.

Can any one help me on this. Any link, suggestion , guidance will be helpful.

***I am having a doubt that may be this is not allowed*** but there is a sample app which is [BubbleUPnP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp&hl=en) in this app they have listed the folders and files. How can i achieve this in my app ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you use the Google Drive API ? Look here : https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro or https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

Comment: In the 'init()' method [here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/spjanson/restdemo/REST.java), use 'DriveScopes.DRIVE' scope. And stay with the REST Api, GDAA has only FILE scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to request the correct Scope.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#AboutAuthorization

To have full access to all files\folders requires the scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

Comment: This is why you can edit posts as well as write comments.