# Android app, Desktop c# app sharing Google Drive App Data

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to sync data between my C# desktop application and an Android application. I got the desktop app running as intended with no problems. However I want to access the data uploaded by the desktop app with the android app and that is where I run into issues.

This is how I connect to drive in my android app.

```
 myGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
    myGoogleApiClient.connect();}
```

This is what happens when i look into my drive Settings>Manage Apps. There appear to be two apps.

[image]

I created an "OAuth 2.0 client ID" in order to access drive from my android device. I assume this is where I made a mistake. How should I do it in order to access the same app data folder on my google drive from both of my apps?

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, you're asking how to access your Drive files using your Android app?

Comment: I am trying to access the same drive application data from my PC and Android, and I am struggling with the Android app. I can get it to access drive but not the same data as my desktop app

Comment: Can you try this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136349/how-to-get-list-of-all-folders-and-files-from-google-drive-in-android). It might be of help.

Comment: I dont think thats what I am looking for. I want to access the same app data folder from both apps, but when I try two of those get created instead of sharing one.

Comment: Have you resolved this? I'm not sure you can access the Android appfolder with your desktop app, vice versa.

Comment: No, unfortunately I did not solve this.

Comment: maybe it's not possible yet