# Access google drive folder upload from C# application from android app with google drive API

Tags: xamarin, google-drive-android-api

I would like to query files uploaded to google drive folder by C# desktop application from an android application.I use google drive API to upload files from C# application with OAuth 2.0 client that i have created in google console.
Then i try to get list of files from an android application(using Xamarin.Android) with another OAuth 2.0 android client under same project.Part off code to retrieve files is shown here:

```
this.GoogleApiClient = new Android.Gms.Common.Apis.GoogleApiClient.Builder(Android.App.Application.Context)
               .AddApi(Android.Gms.Drive.DriveClass.API)
               .AddScope(Android.Gms.Drive.DriveClass.ScopeFile)
               .SetAccountName("xxxx@gmail.com")
               .AddConnectionCallbacks(this)
               .AddOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
               .Build();

GoogleApiClient.Connect();

var query = new Android.Gms.Drive.Query.QueryClass.Builder().AddFilter(Android.Gms.Drive.Query.Filters.Contains(Android.Gms.Drive.Query.SearchableField.Title, "apps.txt")).Build();    

var results = await Android.Gms.Drive.DriveClass.DriveApi.Query(googleApiClient, query).AsAsync<Android.Gms.Drive.IDriveApiMetadataBufferResult>();
```

But it seems that Android.Gms.Drive.DriveClass.ScopeFile returns only files that have been uploaded by same application. It seems a similar question with the one raised here:

[Android app, Desktop c# app sharing Google Drive App Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338921/android-app-desktop-c-sharp-app-sharing-google-drive-app-data)

I wonder if i can add some specific metadata to the files uploaded by C# in order android google API to be able to return these files while querying.
Or make some specific configuration in clients configured in google console under same account.

Comment: Drive API returns the same results regardless of framework or programming language used as long as your following the correct methods indicated in the API. That method would be [Files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list). Although not exactly the same, try referring to this [.NET Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet) on how to list files since Xamarin also uses .NET language.

Comment: I am using google drive android API to query files and not REST API.Android.Gms.Drive.DriveClass.ScopeFile returns only files that have been uploaded by same application. However i added OAuth 2.0 clients(desktop and android) under same google console project and it seems that now it works. Thanks anyway for your answer

Comment: If you want, you can post your code which might be of help to the community.